# Find the moment of inertia of a homogenous solid right circular cylinder around a diameter of its base.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the moment of inertia of a homogenous solid right circular cylinder around a diameter of its base. Express I in terms of radius a, height h and a constant density rho! Hi, I'm just very confused by how to solve this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can approach in the following way :-
Take an elementary disc of infinitesimal thickness at a distance $x$ from the center of the face which is having the diameter.Calculating the linear density(I assume $\rho$ is the density of the body and not linear density)$$\frac{M}{\pi a^2h}=\rho \rightarrow \frac{M}{h}=\sigma=\rho\pi a^2=linear density$$$$\therefore dm= \rho\pi a^2dx$$ moment of inertia of disc about perpendicular axis passing through center is $\frac{mR^2}{2}$ , applying perpendicular axis theorem , moment of inertia about any diameter is $\frac{\frac{mR^2}{2}}{2}=\frac{mR^2}{4}$,following similar reasoning with our elementary disc , moment of inertia about axis $AA'$ is $\frac{ \rho\pi a^2dxa^2}{4}$ , using parallel axis theorem at this point , moment of inertia of the disc about the axis $OO'$ is $\frac{ \rho\pi a^2dxa^2}{4}+\rho\pi a^2dxx^2$, integrating this in the limit 0 to h $$\int^{h}_0\frac{ \rho\pi a^2dxa^2}{4}+\rho\pi a^2dxx^2=\frac{1}{4}Ma^2+\frac{1}{3}Mh^2=\rho \pi a^2h\left (\frac{a^2}{4}+\frac{h^2}{3}\right)$$[image]